# wpf InteropBitmap to bitmap

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, browser

I am having a strange problem.  I am trying to retrieve the images already loaded in webbrowser control.  The following code works fine in a WinForms application:

```
IHTMLControlRange imgRange = (IHTMLControlRange)((HTMLBody)__ie.NativeDocument.BODY).createControlRange();

            foreach (IHTMLImgElement img in __ie.NativeDocument.Images)
            {
                imgRange.add((IHTMLControlElement)img);
                imgRange.execCommand("Copy", false, null);

                System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                using (Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap))
                {
                        bmp.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                        var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
                }
            }
```

But the same code if I use in WPF application gives error on

```
using (Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Clipboard.GetDataObject().......
```

The error is as follows:

> "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Interop.InteropBitmap' to type 'System.Drawing.Bitmap'."

How do I solve this?

Please can anyone provide any guidance.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue you are running into is that there are two different `Clipboard` classes, one for WinForms, and one for `WPF`.  The WinForms one returns bitmaps that are suitable for use with WinForms, i.e. `System.Drawing.Bitmap`, which in the code you are using copies it to a `System.Drawing.Image`.

Those types of bitmaps are not useful with WPF so the fact that you can't convert what the WPF version of the `Clipboard` class is giving you to a type that is useful with WinForms is expected and not really your problem.

Your problem is that for WPF you need a type of bitmap that you can use with WPF: a `BitmapSource`.  That is something you can use with WPF controls like `Image`.  So, back to your question:

- if you are using WPF4 you can use `Clipboard.GetImage` which returns a `BitmapSource`, exactly what you need
- if you are using anything else, you can use Thomas Levesque's technique described [here](http://tomlev2.wordpress.com/2009/02/05/wpf-paste-an-image-from-the-clipboard/)

In summary:

- For WinForms: WinForms clipboard => WinForms bitmaps
- For WPF: WPF clipboard => WPF bitmaps